# C++ std::vectors with predefined sizes

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

While taking a look at a solution for a problem, I came across this implementation of a vector.

```
const int MX = 100000;
std::vector <int> adj[MX];
```

The `push_back()` function doesn't work with this implementation of the vector class, and to add an element, the following code was used:

```
std::ifstream fin ("file.in");
int N = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < (N-1); i++) {
    int A,B; fin >> A >> B;             // reading values from another file
    adj[A].pb(B), adj[B].pb(A);
}
```

The way this code is adding is adding pushing back a value to a certain part of the list, which I imagine as a vector inside the vector of the form:

```
{
    { },
    { }
}
```

In addition, how would I loop through this vector because `for (int n : adj)` does not work. I am not sure what the form of this vector is because this method of looping does not work.

Comment: You don't have a vector of 100000 elements. You have an array of 100000 vectors.

Comment: _"The push_back() function doesn't work"_.  What does that mean?  How do you know?  _"for (int n : adj) does not work"_ What does that mean?  How do you know?  The phrase **does not work** is not a good description of a problem that you are hoping to solve.

Comment: @BillLynch Thanks that helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is C style array of vectors, off the bat you could replace that with `std::array`:

```
std::array<std::vector<int>, MX> adj;
```

To loop through these you would have to use a nested one, the outer loop to go through the array, and the inner one to go through each vector, something like this:

```
const int MX = 3;

//array of 3 vectors
std::array<std::vector<int>, MX> adj {{{1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}}};

for(auto &v : adj){    //for the array
    for(auto i : v){   //for each vector
        std::cout << i << " "; 
    } 
    std::cout << "\n";      
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
```

You can also access individual elements using C style indexing:

```
std::cout << adj[1][0]; // vector element index 0 of array index 1
```

Or in a safer way, using container member `at`:

```
std::cout << adj.at(1).at(0);
```

This would output `5`.

You should be careful though, when randomly filling the array, an array is not meant to have empty elements, otherwise the loops will go through uninitialized array members, which is not ideal, perhaps you are looking for some [other kind of container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).